# What is the fundamental system of equations of space and time?

Tags: special-relativity

What is the fundamental system of equations of space and time? I searched the internet but found no answer anywhere. Who can answer me what is the fundamental system of equations from which all others follow?

Comment: Are you looking for the Einstein equations, just the system of 10 nonlinear hyperbolic PDEs that govern space-time as described by general relativity?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The question seems to be assuming a sort "grand unified theory" approach to science. This might be possible within large areas of science but it is doubtful whether it applies to all of science. Broadly speaking, when one moves from single-body phenomena of the type studied in particle physics to many-body phenomena of the type studied in condensed matter physics, it is not established that the equations describing the collective phenomena can always be deduced from the ones describing the single-particle phenomena. For an example of this, consider superconductivity (especially high-temperature superconductivity). Very likely this is entirely consistent with quantum electrodynamics and other parts of the Standard Model of particle physics, but that does not help very much in finding the right insights to say what is going on and arrive at suitable phenomenological equations.

There is an even stronger sense in which a micro-theory may fail, when it cannot even furnish the right concepts to lead to the observed behaviour. We never know for sure whether this is true of whatever is our latest theory, but very likely each best theory does fail in this way. This is related to a technical discussion of mathematical 'grammars' and 'languages' called the Chomsky hierarchy.

Another difficulty is that at each stage of our knowledge, when we lay out as complete a physical theory as we can, it has never yet had gaps and even inconsistencies. For example, classical electromagnetism looks great until you realise that you can't have classical point particles (because of infinite field energies) and then when you ask how a non-point charged particle can exist the theory has nothing to say. The modern best set of equations would be a combination of the Standard Model of particle physics and Einstein's field equation for general relativity, but these two sets of equations adopt different sets of physical concepts and there is a sense in which the very languages in which they are framed are mutually inconsistent. So then we have the large amount of work on attempts to find a quantum theory of gravity (or a gravitational theory of quantum), which includes a very impressive amount of progress, but again there is no set of equations which we can be confident are right, and even when one writes down mathematical equations from string theory it is often extremely hard to know what physical behaviour they predict. The mathematics is too rich and can describe too many possibilities; we need a way to apply further constraints.

For all these reasons, although the equations of the Standard Model and of General Relativity are an extremely beautiful, wonderful, and impressive achievement of human culture, I am reluctant to write them down as an "answer" to your question. I prefer to encourage you to adopt a different understanding of how science operates and from that perspective ask a different sort of question.